URL Rewrite does not work as expected in Azure WebApp (Windows)
I am trying to use URL Rewrite to rewrite HTTP_HOST and REQUEST URL in Azure WebApp (Windows).
There is an Application Gateway in front of the WebApp, which rewrites the request FQDN.
What I want to do with URL Rewrite
(1) If there is a value in X_ORIGINAL_HOST, assign the value of X_ORIGINAL_HOST to HTTP_HOST.
(2) If the request URL does not start with /en /ja-JP, add /ja-JP/ to the beginning of the URL.
I wrote rules are follows
<rule name="Rule1">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
  <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
  <serverVariables> 
    <set name="HTTP_HOST" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST}" /> 
  </serverVariables> 
</rule>

<rule name="Rule2" stopProcessing="false">
 <match url="^(?!(en|ja-JP)(\/|$)).*$" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/.*$" ignoreCase="true" />
 </conditions> 
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/ja-JP/{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" /> 
</rule> 

However, when the second rule is enabled,
the HTTP_HOST rewrite seems to be restored.
On the other hand, when the second rule is commented out,
the HTTP_HOST rewrite is enabled.
In fact, when I get a trace,
when the second rule is enabled,
GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER is output just before URL_REWRITE_END, with Headname="HOST" HeaderValue="Hostname rewritten by the first rule", Replace="true".
How should I modify the rewrite rules to make the first and second rules valid?
I would appreciate any help from any wise people.

What is the framework and version of your WebApp?How you are deploying the app ?

Framework is .Net Framework 4.8.
I manually deploy a web app. (The file is placed using the kudu console.)
This event can also occur by placing We.Config, which describes the Rewrite rules without placing an application.
Best regards.

I did the same thing on IIS on a local PC.
As a result, the HTTP_HOST server variable expected in the local PC IIS has been rewritten.
This event seems to happen only in App Service.

The issue arises because the second rule processes the request after the first one and seems to overwrite the value set by the HTTP_HOST rewrite in the first rule. To make both rules work correctly, you need to ensure the HTTP_HOST value from the first rule persists while applying the second rule.
For more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Using_Server_Variables
